# Simulate an HTTP request with success or failure using retry logic

Tags: algorithm, go

I want to simulate a re-try option with http like:

> 1. first two http attempts with error (using some faulty urls)
> 2. the third with success (with valid url)

This is a bit tricky any idea how to do it? I try with loop on the `doSomething` method with different url but it doesn't make the point,
which is for example, retry at least 3 times until you get http 200, (success) any idea how could I simulate it?

maybe run in loop on following...

```
www.stackoverflow.com2
www.stackoverflow.com1
www.stackoverflow.com
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dblPh1T0XBu

```
package main

import (
    `fmt`
    `log`
    "net/http"
    `time`

    `github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4`
)

func main() {
    b := backoff.NewExponentialBackOff()
    b.MaxElapsedTime = 3 * time.Second
    retryable := func() error {
        val, err := doSomething("https://www.google.com1")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Println(val)
        return nil
    }

    notify := func(err error, t time.Duration) {
        log.Printf("error: %v happened at time: %v", err, t)
    }

    err := backoff.RetryNotify(retryable, b, notify)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("error after retrying: %v", err)
    }
}

func doSomething(url string) (int, error) {
    res, e := http.Get(url)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occurred: ", e)
        return 500, e
    }
    return res.StatusCode, nil
}
```

The idea on the comment below is part of the problem, I need to use the **http** calls
https://play.golang.org/p/FTR7J2r-QB7

```
package main

import (
    `fmt`
    `log`
    `time`

    `github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4`
)

func main() {
    b := backoff.NewExponentialBackOff()
    b.MaxElapsedTime = 3 * time.Second
    retrybuilder := func (count int) func() error {
        return func() error {
            var succeed bool
            count -= 1
            if count == 0 {
                succeed = true
            }
            val, err := doSomething(succeed)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("response: ", val)
            }
            return err
        }
    }

    notify := func(err error, t time.Duration) {
        log.Printf("error: %v happened at time: %v", err, t)
    }

    err := backoff.RetryNotify(retrybuilder(3), b, notify)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error after retrying: %v", err)
    }
}

func doSomething(succeed bool) (int, error) {
    if !succeed {
        return 500, fmt.Errorf("E_SIMULATED: sim error")
    }
    return 200, nil
}
```

Comment: I am afraid the question is not clear enough. What is it that you want to simulate and why?
Do you mean something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/FTR7J2r-QB7)

Comment: @not-a-robot - yes I need something very similar but with http request , maybe run on may with two faulty url and in the third valid url, is it more clear now ?

Comment: @not-a-robot - I understand that this a bit more tricky, do you have an idea?

Comment: Use an `httptest.Server` that returns something other than 200 on the first two requests.

Comment: @Crowman -  not sure that I got it, could you please provide an example as answer?

Comment: See example in [httptest docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server).
You can add a counter in the handler function to return failure in 3rd call.
Or you could create 3 test servers if you want to hit separate urls.